# openDrawer() retorna siempre como falso y no abre menu, en react-native-drawer v4.x

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

Ya llevo tiempo intentando averiguar el porque la función openDrawer() no genera ninguna acción, no abre, y al hacer console.log de esto solo retorna un "false" como respuesta. He intentado al inicio con navigation.openDrawer() pero esta me indicaba que no es una función (claro que al hacer console.log, del objecto navigation; openDrawer() y closeDrawer, no estaban en este objeto, entonces, busqué soluciones en internet y encontré usar navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer(), el cual, claro que ya no me sale ese error anterior, pero solo retorna "false" cada vez que lo ejecuto.

Cabe destacar que toda la navegación funciona correctamente, solo es el drawer que no funciona bien, quizás puede que me falte algo.
Este es mi codigo:

```
import  React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

    const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
        {
            Home: {
            screen: Perfil,
            },
            Notifications: {
            screen: Notifications,
            },
        }
    ); 

    const OnBoardingNavigator = createStackNavigator(
        {
            Login: LoginSrcreen,
        },
    )

    // Navegación Dashboard
    const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
        {
            Dashboard: { 
                screen: Dashboard, 
            },
            Page1: { 
                screen: Page1,
            },
            Page2: { 
                screen: Page2,
            },
            Page3: { 
                screen: Page3,
            }
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
        },
    )


    const FormsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
        {
            Screen: { 
                screen: Forms,  
                navigationOptions: {
                    headerShown: false,
                  },
            },

        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'Screen',
        },
    )

    const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
        {
            Dashboard: AppNavigator,
            Forms: FormsNavigator,
            Drawer : MyDrawerNavigator,
        },
        {
            defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) =>({
                headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTitle: '',
                headerLeft: () => <Image source={image} style={{ width: 45, height: 30, marginLeft:15 }} />,
                headerRight: () => <IconButton
                icon="menu"
                color={Colors.white}
                size={30}
                onPress={() => {navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}}
              />,
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
            })
        },
    )

    const BaseStack = createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            OnBoarding : OnBoardingNavigator,
            Root: RootStack
        },
    )

    export default createAppContainer(BaseStack);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano! :)